# Custom Desktop Environment

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gui, desktop-environments

Part of a product I plan to launch soon includes having a screen to interface with the product. While I absolutely need a full Ubuntu distribution to run on my PC/backend, to make it look isolated from an actual OS, I want to have the services I run display their metrics on the UI as a full undisturbed screen, i.e. full screen, no taskbars, etc. GNOME-tweak seems limited in capacity in that it only allows you to modify the already existing assets and layout of the desktop, however, I want something that may allow me to replicate the touchscreen in a Tesla. What software tools should I look at to achieve so?

Comment: If you use X (as opposed to Wayland), you can just run one app full screen without any desktop envoirnment at all. That might work for you. Of course, you still need to install an X server (on Arch, for example, you would need `xorg-serveg` and `xorg-xinit` most likely). That could work for you.

Comment: @cocomac That sounds more like what I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion!